# How to dynamically generate a grid view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, dynamic, flutter-layout

I want to generate a grid view using information from a list that is retrieved by an api

How can this be achieved?

Seems like `GridView.builder` method is meant to allow that but there doesn't seem any explanation for the method

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
List<Widget> cardsList = [];

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Team Kitty'),
  ),
  body: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: cardsList.length,
      gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
      //crossAxisCount: (orientation == Orientation.portrait) ? 2 : 3),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(child: cardsList[index]);
      }),
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: addCard(),
    tooltip: 'Add Card',
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Sample with GridView.count()

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
    future: callApi(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return
          (snapshot.data.length == 0) ? Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('No data'),
          ) :
          GridView.count(
            controller: _scrollController,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            crossAxisSpacing: 30.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 23.0,
            childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 9.0,
            children: itemsList
                .map(
                  (Item) =>
                  cardView(Item),
            ).toList(),
          );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        print("Error : " + snapshot.error.toString());
        return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('No data'),
      );
      } else {
        print('no data');
      }
      // While the data is being loaded, show a spinner
      return
        Container(
          child: SpinKitChasingDots(
            color: primaryRed,
          ),
        );
    },
  )
```